# RewriteRule to show root

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I recently finished developing a new website for my domain and today I want to push it "live" by making it available to whoever visits the root of my domain `example.com`.

However, I don't want to be moving moving files back and forth between directories in order to "archive" the old site and have the new one available.

Instead, I added the following RewriteRule in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^((?!(newsite)|(oldsite)).+)$ /newsite/$1 [NC,L]
```

My old website is in the root while the new one under `/newsite`.

Now when I visit my website `example.com` it correctly displays the content of the site which under the directory `/newsite` but without making that visible in the URL. So far so good.

However, now I want the old website to be visible if a special "fake" directory is provided in the URL. So I want `example.com/oldsite` to load the contents from the root.

Here's an illustration of my folder tree, and what I want:

```
root                 <--- accessible from 'example.com/oldsite'
├──index.php        
├──css               <--- accessible from 'example.com/oldsite/css'
├──js
└──newsite           <--- accessible from 'example.com'
   ├──index.php
   ├──css            <--- accessible from 'example.com/css'
   └──js
```

I tried changing the `.htaccess` to:

```
RewriteRule ^((?=oldsite).+)$ $1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^((?!(newsite)|(oldsite)).+)$ /newsite/$1 [NC,L]
```

but this doesn't work. Other things I tried rendered the site in a redirect loop. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these 2 rewrite rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# load newsite if not newsite and not oldsite
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^((?!(?:newsite|oldsite)).*)$ newsite/$1 [NC,L]

# load root if request is newsite
RewriteRule ^oldsite(/.*)?$ /$1 [L,NC]
```